# Require help in understanding buffered channels

Tags: go

I'm having a hard time understanding how buffered channels work. Based on the following example, i'm trying to utilize 2 threads at a time to print out the current time, with approximately 2 second delays between every 2 go calls:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    returnCurrentTime := func() string  {
        return time.Now().String()
    }

    c := make(chan string, 2)

    asyncReturnCurrentTime := func(c chan string) {
        time.Sleep(2001 * time.Millisecond)
        c <- returnCurrentTime()
    }

    for i := 1; i != 7; i++ {
        go asyncReturnCurrentTime(c)
        if(i % 3 == 0) {
            fmt.Println(<- c)
            fmt.Println(<- c)
            fmt.Println(<- c)
            fmt.Println()
        }
    }
}
```

This produces

```
2013-02-27 03:17:50
2013-02-27 03:17:50
2013-02-27 03:17:50

2013-02-27 03:17:52
2013-02-27 03:17:52
2013-02-27 03:17:52
```

What i'm expecting regarding the seconds is 2 second delays between ever 2 go calls and in this case the following result

```
2013-02-27 03:17:50
2013-02-27 03:17:50
2013-02-27 03:17:52 <- 3rd call with 2 buffer slots

2013-02-27 03:17:54
2013-02-27 03:17:54
2013-02-27 03:17:56 <- 3rd call with 2 buffer slots
```

Obviously i misunderstood the concept of buffered channels, would somebody please be kind enough to explain the fault in my logic and how to achieve the expected result?

Thank you

Comment: You have more then two "threads". In this case each go routines acting like a thread so at one point you are running three go routines plus the main thread so that is four "threads".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively, you are running:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    returnCurrentTime := func() string {
        return time.Now().String()
    }

    c := make(chan string, 2)

    asyncReturnCurrentTime := func(c chan string) {
        time.Sleep(2001 * time.Millisecond)
        c <- returnCurrentTime()
    }

    go asyncReturnCurrentTime(c)
    go asyncReturnCurrentTime(c)
    go asyncReturnCurrentTime(c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    fmt.Println()
    go asyncReturnCurrentTime(c)
    go asyncReturnCurrentTime(c)
    go asyncReturnCurrentTime(c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Output:

```
2013-02-26 21:28:22.069581655 -0500 EST
2013-02-26 21:28:22.069688722 -0500 EST
2013-02-26 21:28:22.069695217 -0500 EST

2013-02-26 21:28:24.070985411 -0500 EST
2013-02-26 21:28:24.070999309 -0500 EST
2013-02-26 21:28:24.071002661 -0500 EST
```

> [Send statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements)
>
> Both the channel and the value expression are evaluated before
>   communication begins. Communication blocks until the send can proceed.

The `returnCurrentTime()` expression (the timestamp) is evaluated immediately, before an attempt is made to send. It's not a timestamp for the send. The send may happen later if the buffer is full.

Also, measuring actual send and receive times, the buffering delay for `chan c` is going to be inconsequential: send, send, block, receive, unblock, send.  For example,

```
c <-;  2013-02-26 23:29:34.505456624 -0500 EST
c <-;  2013-02-26 23:29:34.505467030 -0500 EST
<- c;  2013-02-26 23:29:34.505468497 -0500 EST
c <-;  2013-02-26 23:29:34.505518015 -0500 EST

c <-;  2013-02-26 23:31:36.506659943 -0500 EST
c <-;  2013-02-26 23:31:36.506664832 -0500 EST
<- c;  2013-02-26 23:31:36.506669302 -0500 EST
c <-;  2013-02-26 23:31:36.506696540 -0500 EST
```

Comment: Shouldn't the channel buffer limit "2" restrict to 2 maximum calls before receive? If not, what is the point of the buffer limit ?

Comment: You need to understand exactly what your timestamp represents. See my revised answer.